# paste command with Variables instead of files

Tags: posix, paste

I have 3 variables , `TITLES` , `SIZE` and `NUMBER`.
I want to concat them like so
"`NUMBER TITLE SIZE`"
This variables are multi line strings.
eg:

```bsh
echo $NUMBER 
1
2
3
...
```

I know that for files `paste` (GNU coreutils 9.0) can do this.(Lets say my vars are files)

```bsh
paste ./NUMBER ./TITLE ./SIZE
1   ****  123Mb
2   ****  456Gb
3   ****  789Tb
...
```

How can i do the same thing but with variables instead of files? In POSIX shell.